# Serverless Cube.js - No messages published to SNS

Tags: cube.js

Trying to turn a containerized Cube.js deployment into a serverless one. I’m getting Continue wait on every API call, and I notice the `cubejsProcess` lambda is never invoked. I checked SNS reachability by (successfully) publishing a message to it using the AWS SDK in the `cubejs` lambda. The `cubejsProcess` does get invoked with this inserted message. What might be preventing `cubejs` from publishing messages to SNS?

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60943814/error-continue-wait-issue-on-cube-js-backend), however, connectivity to SNS has been verified in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check IAM permissions to see if the `cubejs` Lambda's role. Does the role allow making requests to SNS?

Another thing that could be causing the issue is if the `cubejs` Lambda is in a VPC with no Internet access; calling any AWS API endpoint would fail since they all require an Internet connection.